# Kernel of an irreducible representation on the direct sum of two semisimple Lie algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

Suppose $L=L_1\oplus L_2$, where $L_1,L_2$ are finite-dimensional complex semisimple Lie algebras. Suppose $V$ is a finite-dimensional irreducible representation of $L$ (through $\rho:L\to \mathfrak{gl}(V)$), then I need to show either $L_1$ or $L_2$ act on $V$ trivially.

My proof follows like this: we first compute, for $X_1\in L_1,X_2\in L_2$, that
$$
\rho(X_2)\rho(X_1)=\rho(X_1)\rho(X_2)-[\rho(X_1),\rho(X_2)]=\rho(X_1)\rho(X_2)-\rho[X_1,X_2]=\rho(X_1)\rho(X_2).
$$
The last step follows from the structural theorem of semisimple Lie algebras, which gives $[X_1,X_2]=0$. But how to reason from here?

I am also curious whether the step where I used semisimplicity is correct. My argument comes from the decomposition of semisimple Lie algebras into direct sum of simple ideals. Is this how semisimplicity in the assumption is used?

**EDIT:** I just revisited the definition of a direct sum of Lie algebras, and it seems that the last equality directly follows from definition, but not semisimplicity. How does one apply the semisimplicity condition then?

**EDIT on Sept. 26**
It seems that one could prove $V$ is irreducible as a $L_1-$module. To prove this, we use Weyl's theorem and Schur's lemma. The previous one uses the complex semisimple property to induce that $V$ is completely irreducible as a $L_1-$module. The latter one and the commutative property of $\rho(X_1),\rho(X_2)$ shows that $\rho(X_2)$ acts on the irreducible submodules as scalars. This shows $V$ must be irreducible as a $L_1$ module. Is this argument correct? And how should I continue?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Yes. The computation shows $\rho(L_1)V$ is a subrepresentation and by irreducibility it is either $0$ or $V$. But how should I proceed in the case $\rho(L_1)V=V$?

Comment: This isn't true. Neither summand needs to act trivially. The simplest example being $\mathfrak{sl}_2\oplus\mathfrak{sl}_2$ which acts on $\mathbb{C}^2 \otimes\mathbb{C}^2 \cong \mathbb{C}^4 $ as the natural representation of $\mathfrak{so}_4$ on $\mathbb{C}^4 $

Comment: I think the result that you are looking for is instead that if $V$ is irreducible for $L$ and for $L_1$ then $L_2$ acts trivially

Comment: Cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3826725/96384 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3350849/96384 as follow-up to Callum's comment.

Comment: @Callum I believe I can reduce the original problem to this case. Please kindly refer to my update, and if it is correct, may I ask how should I proceed?

Comment: You cannot prove $V$ is automatically irreducible as an $L_1$ module because it doesn't have to be true. In the example I mentioned above $\mathbb{C}^2 \otimes\mathbb{C}^2$ is irreducible as an $L$-module but as a $L_1$-module it is the union of invariant subspaces of the form $\mathbb{C}^2 \otimes\langle v\rangle$ so is definitely not irreducible.