# Solution verification tensor product of representations of $\mathbf{sl}(2;\mathbb{C})$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am not very familiar with representation theory, but I have an assignment in a Lie groups course which I am the only student taking, and my lecturer is overseas currently so I don’t have anyone else I can ask about this homework assignment. The question is from Hall’s “Lie groups, Lie algebras, and representations” and it is exercise 12 from chapter 4 of the latest edition. I would like it if someone could please tell me if I am on track with the first part of the question, and also some hints about how to get started with the second part would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Recall the spaces $V_m$ introduced in section 4.2, viewed as representations of the Lie algebra $\mathbf{sl}(2;\mathbb{C})$. In particular, consider the space $V_1$ (which has dimension 2).

> Question 1:
> Regard $V_1\otimes V_1$ as a representation of $\mathbf{sl}(2;\mathbb{C})$, as in definition 4.20. Show that this representation is not irreducible.

Solution:

Definition 4.20 states that if we have two representations $\pi_1,\pi_2$ of $\mathbf{sl}(2;\mathbb{C})$ both acting on the space $$V_1 := \{f(z_1,z_2) =a_0z_1+a_1z_2~:~\text{$a_0,a_1\in \mathbb{C}$, $z_1, z_2$ complex variables}\}$$ then for any $X\in \mathbf{sl}(2;\mathbb{C})$ we find the tensor product of representations $\pi_1\otimes \pi_2$ is a representation of $\mathbf{sl}(2;\mathbb{C})$ acting on $V_1\otimes V_1$ given by $$(\pi_1\otimes\pi_2)(X) = \pi_1(X)\otimes I + I\otimes \pi_2(X) \,.$$

We will show that this representation is not irreducible by finding a nontrivial invariant subspace. Without loss of generality we may assume that $\pi_1, \pi_2$ are each irreducible representations of $\textbf{sl}(2;\mathbb{C})$ over $V_1$ otherwise the result is obvious.

If we consider the action of some $X\in \textbf{sl}(2;\mathbb{C})$ on an element $f\otimes g\in V_1\otimes V_1$, this representation looks like
\begin{align*}
  (\pi_1\otimes\pi_2)(X)(f\otimes g)
  &= \pi_1(X)\otimes I (f\otimes g) + I\otimes \pi_2(X) (f\otimes g)\\
  &= \pi_1(X)(f)\otimes I(g) +I(f)\otimes \pi_2(X)(g) \,.
\end{align*}

Consider the nontrivial subspace of $V_1\otimes V_1$ given by $V_1\otimes \{0\}$. It is clear that this is an invariant subrepresentation of the above representation, since we have for any $X\in \textbf{sl}(2;\mathbb{C})$, given some $f\otimes 0 \in V_1\otimes \{0\}$:

$$(\pi_1\otimes \pi_2)(X)(f\otimes 0) = \pi_1(X)(f)\otimes 0+f\otimes 0 \in V_1\otimes \{0\} \,.$$

Therefore, we have found a nontrivial invariant subspace, and so this representation is not irreducible.

> Question 2:
> Now, view $V_1\otimes V_1$ as a representation of $\mathbf{sl}(2;\mathbb{C})\oplus \mathbf{sl}(2;\mathbb{C})$, as in definition 4.19. Show that this representation is irreducible.

Defintion 4.19 states that a tensor product representation of $\mathbf{sl}(2;\mathbb{C})\oplus \mathbf{sl}(2;\mathbb{C})$ takes the form $$(\pi_1\otimes\pi_2)(X,Y) = \pi_1(X)\otimes I + I\otimes \pi_2(Y) \,.$$

Comment: $V_1 \otimes \{0\}$ **is** a trivial subspace since $f \otimes 0 = 0 \otimes 0$

Comment: Instead you want to see that the symmetric and antisymmetric tensors form two subrepresentations. Hint: show that the action of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ commutes with swapping the order of the tensors i.e. $v\otimes w \mapsto w\otimes v$

Comment: Oh ok cheers I am also not too familiar with tensors but I will have a read about symmetric and antisymmetric tensors and see what I come up with. Thank you!

Comment: Ok I believe that since I assume the individual representations to be irreducible, this means that they are isomorphic to a specific representation given in the book. In particular $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ are both the same, so I am convinced that swapping the order of the tensors doesn't change the result. I am not sure how to turn this information in to a subrepresentation!

Answer (score 2):

As I noted in the comments, $V_1 \otimes \{0\}$ is in fact a trivial subspace (by which I mean it is $\{0\}$ rather than a trivial representation). So we instead want to find that $V_1 \otimes V_1 = \Lambda^2 V_1 \oplus S^2 V_1$ as representations. Note you do not need to show that $\pi_1 = \pi_2$, nor that $V_1$ is irreducible as that is in the definition of $V_1$. It is defined not just as a vector space but one carrying a particular representation.

We can prove a much more general fact here.
Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie algebra and $\pi:\mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{gl}(V)$ a representation. Then $V \otimes V = \Lambda^2 V \oplus S^2 V$ is a decomposition into subrepresentations.
Let's denote
$$ v \odot w = v\otimes w + w \otimes v$$
and
$$ v \wedge w = v\otimes w - w \otimes v$$
We call the span of all $v \odot w$, $S^2V$ and the span of $v \wedge w$, $\Lambda^2V$. It is not too hard to see that $V \otimes V = \Lambda^2 V \oplus S^2 V$ as a vector space.

Then $$\begin{aligned}(\pi \otimes \pi)(X)(v\odot w) &= (\pi(X)v) \otimes w + v\otimes(\pi(X)w) + (\pi(X)w) \otimes v + w\otimes(\pi(X)v) \\&= \pi(X)v \odot w + v \odot \pi(X)w.\end{aligned}$$
This (by linearity) shows $S^2 V$ is closed under the action of $\mathfrak{g}$ and so is a subrepresentation and we can do the same with $\Lambda^2 V$. So $V \otimes V$ is never irreducible. Note I have made no assumptions about the irreducibility of $V$ or even semisimplicity,etc. of $\mathfrak{g}$ and I don't show that $S^2 V, \Lambda^2 V$ are irreducible. In general, they do not have to be even if $V$ is (although they are in your example).

The ideas here generalise to a very important part of the representation theory of Lie algebras. For example, you can show that the action of $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ on $V^{\otimes k} = V\otimes \cdots \otimes V$ commutes with the action of the symmetric group $S_k$, permuting the order of the tensor products. The resulting decomposition into simultaneous irreducible representations of $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ and $S_k$ is called Schur-Weyl duality.

As to question 2, you can show, by considering the action of elements like $(X,0)$ and $(0,Y)$, that any invariant subspace of $V_1 \otimes V_1$ must be a tensor product of invariant subspaces in each copy and since they are each irreducible there are no proper invariant subspaces.

Comment: +1. Just saying that question 2 is essentially the direction "$\Leftarrow$" in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3826725/96384 which can turn out to be a little more intricate than expected, depending on what theoretical background one is allowed to take for granted.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Ah good catch, I had a fairly simple argument in mind which must either be wrong or be depending implicitly on something stronger. For this example at least, you can prove it by hand if needed (which is probably what the exercise is intending).